# Allow upnp/dlna access to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, dlna

I'm trying to access my Windows 8 laptop via dlna but am receiving an access denied message. I'm using both a Sony network player and BubblesoftUpnp on my android and they can see the laptop (but get the error when accessing).

I've found options within Home Group sharing to allow access but neither the Android device or Sony device can be part of a Home Group (wrong assumption)?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this going, I think the Home Group settings had me confused. Instead of through that area, I followed these steps:

1. Open Control Panel in Windows 8
2. Navigate to **Network and Internet**
3. Under **Network and Sharing Center** selected **View computers and devices**
4. Right clicked on the Phone and Sony player (which both appeared as **Media Devices**) and selected **Allow streaming to this device**
5. It worked - yay!